# IE 8 doesn't save the initial configuration after I executed it as Administrator

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I had to execute IE 8 once as Administrator in Windows 7 because it is needed to install the protection module from my bank so I can access online banking.

After that every single time I open IE 8 as a limited user the stupid configuration wizard apears.

If I configure everything and close IE 8 it is displayed again once I reopen it.

Anyone knows how to solve this? I just use IE 8 to access online banking, but it is very annoying to have that wizard poping up every single time I open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[How to Disable Internet Explorer 8 Welcome Screen (Tour and RunOnce) for All Users](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-ie8-tour-welcome-screen-runonce-all-users/)**

the easiest of all methods: use this [reg file](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/q3-09/ie8-tour-disable.zip) (**undo** included).

Comment: Thanks, just disabled it using the gpedit.msc. Worked flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

Does your bank's "protection module" actually support IE8 officially?  Hell, does it even support Windows 7 officially?  My guess is not and you'd have better luck using the officially supported browser/OS.

If you really want to force it, you're probably going to have to figure out for yourself what the wizard is trying to do and failing at.  Grab a copy of [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and let it run while you go through the wizard.  Then stop the scan and look for Access Denied errors in the various calls.  That should get you started.

Comment: The protection module has nothing to do with it, the problem started after I executed IE8 as Administrator.
But yes, it supports IE 8 and Windows 7 officially.

Comment: My mistake.  I thought you had meant that the protection module itself had a wizard you were trying to get rid of.  I didn't realize you were talking about the IE 8 welcome wizard.